# number in terminal undefine or NaN

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have data in mongo. I fetch this data from mongo to screen. Then I want update data, by onClick (I select id) and send it to backend /api/folder
I can see object in terminal, BUT I cannot modify it.
Do you know why? Thanks

```
import db from "@/utils/db";
import Team from '@/modules/Team'


const handler = async (req, res) => {
  
  console.log(req.body)    // { id: '64501115948ae9070cdd5ba5' }

  await db.connect();


  const team = await Team.findById(req.query.id);

  console.log('team', team)
  console.log('name', team.name)
  console.log('game', team.game1)
  
  team.game1 += 1

  await team.save()

  await db.disconnect(); 
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'success '})
};

export default handler
```

terminal output / team.game1 === undefine
can you please tell me why is undefine and how to fix it?
thanks

```
{ id: '64501115948ae9070cdd5ba5' }
use previous connection
teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeem {
  _id: new ObjectId("64501115948ae9070cdd5ba5"),
  name: 'Boston',
  img: '/bos.png',
  color: '#0800ff',
  updatedAt: 2023-05-02T16:32:57.387Z,
  game1: 5,              // trying modify this one
  game2: 0,
  game3: 0,
  game4: 0,
  game5: 0,
  game6: 0,
  game7: 0
}
name Boston Bruins
game undefined    //   <= here
```

I dont understand it, data are there, BUT if I want to select it I am getting undefined.

Comment: I am trying alse this :

Comment: console.log('game1', Number(team.game1))    // NaN
  console.log('game1', parseInt(team.game1))  // NaN

Comment: hey @erza try this.. to console.. console.log(parseInt(team && team?.game1) if this code works just lemme know I will help you more..

Comment: I got NaN with your solution

Comment: All games [game1, game2...] are undefined

Comment: can you please reshare result of all console.. if possible?

Comment: yes I can but I got undefined or NaN. Dont Understand this. I can see it there, but if I want to select specific game I am not able to.

Answer (score 0):

Hey erza could you please replace your code-

```
const handler = async (req, res) => {
  
  console.log(req.body)    // { id: '64501115948ae9070cdd5ba5' }

  await db.connect();


  const team = await Team.findById(req.query.id);

  console.log('team', team)
  console.log('name', team.name)
  console.log('game', team.game1)
  
  team.game1 += 1

  await team.save()

  await db.disconnect(); 
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'success '})
};
```

with my code-

```
const handler = async (req, res) => {
  
  console.log(req.body)

  await db.connect();


  const team = await Team.findById(req.query.id).lean().exec();

  console.log('team', team)
  console.log('name', team.name)
  console.log('game', team.game1)
  
  team.game1 += 1

  await Team.findByIdAndUpdate(req.query.id, { $set: team }).exec();

  await db.disconnect(); 
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'success '})
};
```

if this doesn't work just lemme know ii will help you more..

Comment: Right now I am getting number instead of NaN BUT dont update database

Comment: console.log('game', team.game1)   === game 1 // it is good but database in mondo is not updated

Comment: first can you check that your number is really updated before save? by using console?

Comment: I checked it , I ckecked database in mongo,    dont want to update him

Comment: no no.. i mean.. before saving to the database is the team?.game1 really updated?.. so please console.. 
console.log("check updated value",team.game1+=1)

Comment: it seems it is not updated. still same number

Comment: Sorry my bad , yes it is updated.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix this problem? Please let me know. THANK YOU.

Comment: const team = await Team.findById(req.query.id);
change const to let.. and give another try,...

Comment: still not working,

Comment: So forst create const to save vale of team then update by id..

Comment: I can help you more on discord- hypervarun#6188 or you can share your discord thanks

Comment: https://discord.gg/n24fTm2f

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it, I change my mind and set new data in mongo database, BUT I DID NOT CHANGE MODULESCHEMA in pc. I saw data in database but could not change it because of module wasn't change! I will remember it!!!!